# React redux how to compare two obj arrays with filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, filtering

in the action of my reduceur
I get an array,
that I would like to filter with another table,
I would like to check certain value
how to include the other table in the filter?
(without return)
because i will put a le

```js
dbz: [{
      min: 300
      max: 9000
      name: 'goku'
    },

    {
      min: 200
      max: 7000
      name: 'vegeta'
    },

  ],

  dbs: [{
      min: 200
      max: 7000
      name: 'picollo'
    },

    {
      min: 300
      max: 9000
      name: 'gohan'
    },

    {
      min: 20
      max: 800
      name: 'trunks'
    },

    {
      min: 10
      max: 700
      name: 'goten'
    },

  ],


  let samepower = dbs.filter(({
    sayien
  }) => sayien.min !== dbz.min && sayien.max !== dbz.max);
```

the idea is to have an array with only 'goten' and 'trunks' ..
to remove 'gohan' and 'picollo' because they have a 'max' and 'min' equal to 'goku' and ' vegeta'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array's method `filter` and `some` to simplify the answer.

```js
const filtered = (dbs, dbz) => {
  return dbs.filter((ii) =>
    dbz.some((jj) => ii.min === jj.min && ii.max === jj.max)
  );
};

const database = {
  dbz: [
    { min: 300, max: 9000, name: "goku" },
    { min: 200, max: 7000, name: "vegeta" },
  ],
  dbs: [
    { min: 200, max: 7000, name: "picollo" },
    { min: 300, max: 9000, name: "gohan" },
    { min: 20, max: 800, name: "trunks" },
    { min: 10, max: 700, name: "goten" },
  ],
};
console.log(filtered(database.dbs, database.dbz));
```